# Button within RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design

I am using a RecyclerView within my app. I implemented this with a custom item touch listener as described in

[Sliderd's Material Design Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD)

My TouchListener looks like this:

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener  implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.v(getClass().getName(), "onSingleTapUp " + e);
            return true;
            //return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            Log.v(getClass().getName(), "onLongPress" + e);
        }
    });
    Log.v(getClass().getName(), "construtcor invoked");
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    Log.v(getClass().getName(), "onTouchEvent " + e);
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}
}
```

Now as the User Ravi is asking [here](http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/) I want to add a button within each item of the recycler view. But if I click this button, the item click listener is also fired. How can I implement a click listener for the button without having any side effects for the item itself?

Comment: I think in `onInterceptTouchEvent()` you could do something like `if(child instanceof Button){...}` to get only the `Button` click. Else, you could add the `OnClickListener` in your `Adapter` in `onBindViewHolder` with something like `holder.button.setOnClickListener(..)`

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think [Extend a Child View's Touchable Area](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate) can help. I'll try to add some code snippet regarding the `RecyclerView` later.

> The snippet below does the following:
>
> - Gets the `parent view` and posts a `Runnable` on the `UI thread`. This ensures that the parent lays out its children before calling the `getHitRect()` method.
> - The `getHitRect()` method gets the child's hit rectangle (touchable area) in the parent's coordinates.
> - Finds the `ImageButton` child view and calls `getHitRect()` to get the bounds of the child's touchable area.
> - Extends the bounds of the `ImageButton's` hit rectangle.
>     Instantiates a `TouchDelegate`, passing in the expanded hit rectangle and the `ImageButton` child view as parameters.
> - Sets the `TouchDelegate` on the parent view, such that touches within the touch delegate bounds are routed to the child.

Original, without any valuable information so far:

I think in `onInterceptTouchEvent()` you could do something like 
    if(child instanceof Button){...}
to get only the `Button` click. But this looks bad. You could also check if the Ids match:

```
if(child.getId() == R.id.myRvButton){...}
```

Else, you could add the `OnClickListener` in your `Adapter` in `onBindViewHolder` with something like `holder.button.setOnClickListener(..)`. But if you want another `Click Event` if the user clicks on the item, you can try the above methods.

Comment: You have described three different methods. Nice ideas. But the first two do not work. The code does not run into the body of the if statement. In the third approach both, the button click and the the recyclerview item click is triggered.

Comment: Ok, sorry that the first 2 don't work, haven't thought through this. Maybe reading through [this](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html), especially the last section will help you. I'll edit the answer to get some valuable information in it.